# Logging in to a database using encrypted keys

Tags: encryption, plsqldeveloper

How to log into a db using encrypted keys ? If I use the encrypted string for the password to a particular database , can I login to the database ?If no then how to program the automatic decryption ?

Comment: @Boys3nb3rry : Thanks for your reply . But first I want to undesratnd what happens functionally  ..do we provide "the encrypted key " and it is automatically decrypted or what ?
My code will be somewhat like the one in the following link :
https://www.experts-exchange.com/questions/26448742/Example-of-DBMS-CRYPTO-ENCRYPT-AES256.html

Comment: If you use encryption then you always need some kind of key. If you're accessing the database then you need the password/key somewhere nearby. If you encrypt the password/key with another password/key, then you need to store them somewhere. No matter how often you encrypt something, you will always have some kind of key lying around. Do you have a TPM/HSM which might work as a keystore? Then you could at least limit the decryption to a single machine and require the attacker to steal the actual hardware.

Comment: @Boys3nb3rry : About code, I am using the one in the link . But , what I want to know what happens functionally ,do we enter the key , the password or something else ?